# CGAL polygon mesh processing boolean operations crash

Tags: cgal

I want to use CGAL's polygon mesh processing package to perform boolean operations on two meshes.
The problem is that the corefinement_and_union example crashes:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement.h>


#include <fstream>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<K::Point_3>             Mesh;

namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* filename1 = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "blobby.off";
  const char* filename2 = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : "eight.off";
  std::ifstream input1(filename1);
  std::ifstream input2(filename2);

  Mesh mesh1, mesh2;

  input1 >> mesh1;

  std::cout << mesh1.number_of_vertices() << std::endl; //mesh1 input OK

  input1.close();
  input2 >> mesh2;
  input2.close();

  std::cout << mesh2.number_of_vertices() << std::endl; //mesh2 input OK

  Mesh out;
  bool valid_union = PMP::corefine_and_compute_union(mesh1,mesh2, out); //crashes

  if (valid_union)
  {
    std::cout << "Union was successfully computed\n";
    std::ofstream output("union.off");
    output << out;
    return 0;
  }
  std::cout << "Union could not be computed\n";
  return 1;
}
```

I am using cgal 5.0 as a header only library, with boost 1.71.0 v14.1, Eigen 3.3.7, and msvc 2017. I tried running the msvc debugger on PMP::corefine_and_compute_union(mesh1,mesh2, out), but to no avail...

Any ideas why this is happening and how to get it to work on MSVC 2017?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [documention](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#gad7e1741a7ce41a5846cf86494982ca8b), you will see that there are some preconditions that must be met. Most probably one of your input mesh has some self-intersections. On the same documentation page, you will also find the named parameter `throw_on_self_intersection` that if set to `true` will make the function throw an exception in case your input has a self-intersection in the neighborhood of the intersection.